# Alternative solution for ActiveX with Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, browser, activex, citrix

I have a .NET web app that is served to our end users via Citrix using IE11. The web app uses an ActiveX control in the browser to get access to the Citrix client details, ie, it's environment variables.

This allows the browser to automatically identity the terminal that the web app is running from and adapt its behaviour to suit that particular terminal.

For various reasons, we need to remove IE11 and switch to Chrome for our browser, which lacks ActiveX.

I'm not an expert with Citrix and I am open to alternative modern solutions that avoids ActiveX and lets the Chrome browser access the Citrix client details.